# Composite literal

Tags: loops, go

I encountered a situation in Go, which I couldn't find any solution. The problem starts with below piece of code:

```
  graph := chart.BarChart{
        Title: "Remote#1 Bar Chart",
        Background: chart.Style{
        Padding: chart.Box{
        Top: 40,
            },
        },
        Height:   512,
        BarWidth: 60,
        Bars: []chart.Value{
            {Value: 5.25, Label: "Blue"},
            {Value: 4.88, Label: "Green"},
            {Value: 4.74, Label: "Gray"},
            /* composite Literal continues */
       },
    }
```

In Bars field, I might have several (Value:Label) items (more than 100) and it does not make sense if I would hard coded all of items.
I was wondering how could I use loop iteration to solve this problem?

Comment: Why should it not make sense to hardcode the values? How else could you define all those values?

Comment: you mean there is no other way even I have 1000 input pairs ?

Comment: You have to hardcode them somewhere, right? You can put them in a file and read them, or you can put them in a JSON string and unmarshal them. Either case, they have to be entered somewhere.

Comment: There are a few approaches for entering a 1000 input pairs. What is the original source for the data?  Will you need to change the data in the future?

Comment: The source for the pairs are the output of a around 20minutes simulation. 
(Number of occurrence, i-th second) 

So, it is highly possible to have variable number of pairs.

Comment: One approach is to modify the simulation program to write a Go source file with the definitions.  Another approach is to write to a data file and slurp the file up at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate the `values` array elsewhere in your program.

```
values := calculateValues()
// or
values := hardcodedValues()
// or
values := readValuesFromFile()
// or
values := requestValuesFromServer()
```

Then you can initialize your struct using that array:

```
graph := chart.BarChart{
    Title: "Remote#1 Bar Chart",
    Background: chart.Style{
        Padding: chart.Box{
            Top: 40,
        },
    },
    Height:   512,
    BarWidth: 60,
    Bars: values,
}
```